# Program to display the prime factors of an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was trying to make a program that takes a number as input and displays it ans in list format the program is:

```
# we ask for input
num = int(input('enter the number of which you would like to find prime factors of\n='))
div_list = []  # we create an empty list to store all the divisors of the number
prime_div = []  # we create a list for all the prime divisors
for _ in range(2, num-1):  # we check all the divisors
    if num % _ == 0:
        div_list.append(_)  # we add all the divisors to the list
for i in range(len(div_list)):  # this loop will run the next loop for the duration of all the nums
    for j in range(2, div_list[i]):
        if div_list[i] % j == 0:
            pass
        else:
            prime_div.append(div_list[i])


print('the list of all the prime factors is')
print(prime_div)
```

but when I run this program it gives me input of only 1 number:

```
enter the number of which you would like to find prime factors of
=49
the list of all the prime factors is
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

I do not understand why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: suggestion : try not to use '_' as a variable.

Comment: ok will keep that in my mind

Comment: @RamPandey `_` is generally used as a placeholder in iteration when the actual **value** is not going to be used, but rather you just need the looping construct (this situation is admittedly somewhat rare, but also not too unusual). When you start using `_`'s value, consider renaming it to something more informative, as @Taohidul Islam suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem (You were using extra indentation to your code. I have commented out in the program):

```
num = int(input('enter the number of which you would like to find prime factors of\n='))
div_list = []  # we create an empty list to store all the divisors of the number
prime_div = []  # we create a list for all the prime divisors
for _ in range(2, num-1):  # we check all the divisors
    if num % _ == 0:
        div_list.append(_)  # we add all the divisors to the list

for i in range(len(div_list)):  # this loop will run the next loop for the duration of all the nums
    for j in range(2, div_list[i]):
        if div_list[i] % j == 0:
            pass
    else: #This line will execute if div_list[i] is a prime number. You were executing else clause again and again
        prime_div.append(div_list[i]) #removed extra indentation, this was causing your error


print('the list of all the prime factors is')
print(prime_div)
```

Note : please try to avoid using `_` as a variable or placeholder in python.

Comment: yes this worked but could you explain me what was wrong with my code please?

Comment: Your code can be more optimized. I haven't added the complex codes to make it easier for you. I you want then I can optimize it's time complexity but in that case your code will be bigger. Though you are a beginner so I avoided that portion.

Comment: @user1055395 yeah I know that, but I wanted to leave this code as simple as possible.